# Is it possible to link Private Keys and Certificates across Keychains?

Tags: keychain

I've been given ownership of various iOS apps to build, and submit to iTunes Connect, but have run into a very obnoxious issue. Distribution Certificates must be uniquely named, and due to various reasons I have 2 certificates with a single individuals name.

If there are duplicate named certificates, even though they have unique IDs, the build process dies with a Code Sign error that states certificates must be uniquely named. This leads me to a situation where I have to delete the signed certificate(s) I have, download the one I want, rinse, repeat.

And now there's a more difficult problem. I'm reaching a point where these builds are mostly able to be run completely automated via the `xcodebuild` and `xcrun` command line binaries, except for the above problem.

Is it possible to store the Public/Private keys somewhere "global", that will be available to any keychain request, and make a new keychain to hold only a single signed certificate, but allow the two keychains to work together in order to pass code signing?

Comment: Despite how conflicted I am, it is my opinion that this question is on-topic for AD based off the fact that it is only functionally about the Keychain Access utility. The only thing it has to do with code/programming is the fact that it has to pass code signing. But the ultimate underlying procedure exists solely within the built-in Keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to link private keys and certificates across multiple Keychains. There needs be a third hidden item called an [identity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-330262) that bonds these two items together. The identity, certificate, and private key need to be in the same Keychain.

### Specify the Keychain

Using Keychain Access, create a separate Keychain with a certificate and private key in each. In your situation this will mean creating two separate keychains.

Tell [codesign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/codesign.1.html) to look for your specific Keychain using the command line option `--keychain`; the path provided to the Keychain must be absolute.

You can provide this option and path to `codesign` within Xcode through the build settings user interface.

Comment: Would you happen to know if using an identity will also work around the 'duplicate named certificate' limitation?

Comment: If you can specify a specific identity, then I believe it will. My understanding is that an identity binds a certificate and private key uniquely.

Comment: That's awesome. Even though I'm not in a position to execute this activity anymore, I will try to reproduce a test case and verify it in order to accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: You may find the following StackOverflow question useful in setting up Xcode and Keychain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355637/using-a-non-default-keychain-in-xcode/6645998